# Why use spyOn instead of jasmine.createSpy?

Tags: jasmine

What is the difference between

> jasmine.createSpy('someMethod')

And

> spyOn(someObject, 'someMethod')

And why should one choose to use spyOn?

My guess is that the first alternative will match the method someMethod no matter in what object it's contained but spyOn will only match if it's contained in someObject. Thus making createSpy just a more generic matcher?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The difference is that you should have a method on the object with `spyOn`

```
const o = { some(): { console.log('spied') } };
spyOn(o, 'some');
```

while the mock method is created for your with `createSpy()`:

```
const o = {};
o.some = jasmine.createSpy('some');
```

The advantage of the `spyOn` is that you can call the original method:

```
spyOn(o, 'some').and.callThrough();
o.some(); // logs 'spied'
```

And as @estus says the original method is restored after the test in case of `spyOn`. This should be done manually when it's reassigned with.

Comment: More importantly, original method is restored after the test in case of `spyOn`. This should be done manually when it's reassigned with `o.some = `.

Comment: @EstusFlask just want to clarify your statement, when using `spyOn`, after the it() executes, it will restore the spied method's original implementation?

Comment: @ajgo It won't, unless you take care of it - and you need to because it's a good practice. jest.restoreAllMocks and restoreMocks config option are responsible for that.

Comment: Does it mean spyOn will not unspy at the end of test execution? Btw I'm not using jest...i use karma-jasmine

Answer (score 12):

Additionally to the other fine answer:

- Use `spyOn()` to spy (intercept) an existing method on an object to track calls of other modules to it.
- Use `jasmine.createSpy()` to create a function that can be passed as callback or [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) handler to track call-backs.