# How to test shared component's method in Angular 2 unit testing?

Tags: angular

How can I test a shared components method with Angular 2 unit testing? I need to test whether a shared components method has been called or not.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please proofread your questions before posting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **spyOn** or **createSpy**. About the difference between them:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45074442/5709697